# Replace Function on Select Statement, delete (-)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query in a stored procedure trying to insert into this table some amounts:

| KPI | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| First | - |
| Second | -100 |
| Third | 200 |

I'm trying to null all '-' records but when I replace it, it deletes the negative sign on the number too.

```
SELECT
    kpi,
    TO_NUMBER (REPLACE (amount, '-', NULL)),
FROM dual
```

| KPI | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| First | null |
| Second | 100 |
| Third | 200 |

Any other idea to avoid this to happen and have this as result?

| KPI | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| First | null |
| Second | -100 |
| Third | 200 |

Thanks!

Comment: Amount is a text field?

Comment: @June7 from 'orginal' source yes, I'm converting it to_number on ODS.

Comment: Why do you show Replace on KPI field instead of AMOUNT?

Comment: @June7 ugh my bad, edited it already, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULLIF` can be used to replace whole values *(not just characters in strings)* if those values match something.

```
SELECT
  KPI,
  NULLIF(amount, '-')  AS amount  -- If the amount is '-' return a NULL instead
FROM
  yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two other simple ways not mentioned in other answers to clean up the `-` values seen below. I would recommend using the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` method because this would also handle any spaces in the `AMOUNT` column.

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (KPI, AMOUNT)
    AS
        (SELECT 'First', '-' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Second', '-100' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Third', '200' FROM DUAL)
SELECT kpi,
       amount,
       RTRIM (amount, '-')                                                    amt1,
       CASE validate_conversion (amount AS NUMBER) WHEN 1 THEN amount END     AS amt2
  FROM sample_data;
```